# Symbolic matrix not completely simplified in Matlab but simplified in Octave

Tags: matlab, octave, symbolic-math

I have a 4x4 matrix containing symbolic trigonometric expressions. I wish to simplify each expression inside the matrix, so I'm using 'simplify'. Matlab, however, is not simplifying the 4th column of the matrix for some reason. The same code in Octave gives me the correct, most simplified output. I've attached the .m code and Matlab and Octave outputs below.

```
syms t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 a1 a2 a3 real;

A1 = [[cos(t1) 0 -sin(t1) 0]; [sin(t1) 0 cos(t1) 0]; [0 -1 0 0]; [0 0 0 1]];
A2 = [[cos(t2) -sin(t2) 0 a1*cos(t2)]; [sin(t2) cos(t2) 0 a1*sin(t2)]; [0 0 1 0]; [0 0 0 1]];
A3 = [[cos(t3) -sin(t3) 0 a2*cos(t3)]; [sin(t3) cos(t3) 0 a2*sin(t3)]; [0 0 1 0]; [0 0 0 1]];
A4 = [[cos(t4) 0 sin(t4) 0]; [sin(t4) 0 -cos(t4) 0]; [0 1 0 0]; [0 0 0 1]];
Af = [[cos(t5) 0 -sin(t5) a3*cos(t5)]; [sin(t5) 0 cos(t5) a3*sin(t5)]; [0 -1 0 0]; [0 0 0 1]];

T3f = A4 * Af;
T2f = A3 * T3f;
T1f = A2 * T2f;
T0f = A1 * T1f
T = simplify(T0f)

T = subs(T, t2+t3+t4, sym(0));
T = simplify(T)
T = subs(T, t1+t5, sym(0));
T = simplify(T)
```

Final T given by Matlab:

```
T =

[ 1,  0, 0, cos(t1)*(a1*cos(t2) + cos(t2)*(a2*cos(t3) + a3*cos(t3)*cos(t4)*cos(t5) - a3*cos(t5)*sin(t3)*sin(t4)) - sin(t2)*(a2*sin(t3) + a3*cos(t3)*cos(t5)*sin(t4) + a3*cos(t4)*cos(t5)*sin(t3))) - a3*sin(t1)*sin(t5)]
[ 0,  0, 1, sin(t1)*(a1*cos(t2) + cos(t2)*(a2*cos(t3) + a3*cos(t3)*cos(t4)*cos(t5) - a3*cos(t5)*sin(t3)*sin(t4)) - sin(t2)*(a2*sin(t3) + a3*cos(t3)*cos(t5)*sin(t4) + a3*cos(t4)*cos(t5)*sin(t3))) + a3*cos(t1)*sin(t5)]
[ 0, -1, 0,                              - a1*sin(t2) - cos(t2)*(a2*sin(t3) + a3*cos(t3)*cos(t5)*sin(t4) + a3*cos(t4)*cos(t5)*sin(t3)) - sin(t2)*(a2*cos(t3) + a3*cos(t3)*cos(t4)*cos(t5) - a3*cos(t5)*sin(t3)*sin(t4))]
[ 0,  0, 0,                                                                                                                                                                                                           1]
```

Final T given by Octave:

```
T = (sym 4×4 matrix)

⎡1  0   0  a₁⋅cos(t₁)⋅cos(t₂) + a₂⋅cos(t₁)⋅cos(t₂ + t₃) + a₃⎤
⎢                                                           ⎥
⎢0  0   1       (a₁⋅cos(t₂) + a₂⋅cos(t₂ + t₃))⋅sin(t₁)      ⎥
⎢                                                           ⎥
⎢0  -1  0            -a₁⋅sin(t₂) - a₂⋅sin(t₂ + t₃)          ⎥
⎢                                                           ⎥
⎣0  0   0                          1                        ⎦
```

Any help fixing this in Matlab is appreciated. I'm using Matlab R2017a.